# Buttons aren't functioning correctly with osascript

Tags: bash, button, scripting, osascript

I have a dialog box that has two buttons, "OK" and "Cancel", I'd like to have the "OK" button launch a website, and the cancel button will stop the script. Right now both the "OK and "Cancel" buttons are launching the website. What am I missing here?

```
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "Things are broke \r \rPress OK to launch Google" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"}'
if [ "button returned:OK" ]; then 
    open "http://www.google.com"
else
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: i think `if..else` like this `if [[ $* = *"button returned:OK"* ]]`...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options. The first is easier maybe:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "Things are broke \r \rPress OK to launch Google" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"}' >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then open "http://www.google.com"; else exit 0; fi
```

Or capture and parse the output of `osascript` like this:

```
res=$(osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "Things are broke \r \rPress OK to launch Google" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"}' 2>/dev/null)
```

Then you can check like this:

```
if [[ $res == *OK* ]]; then 
  echo OK
fi
```

Comment: The first option no longer works.